# How to show sub router?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose I have this controller:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function __constructor()
    {
        parent::__constructor();
        echo 'test';
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $view['site'] = true;
        $view['view_home'] = lang('home');
        $view['view_home_url'] = base_url();
        $view['view_name'] = lang('home');
        $view['content'] = 'site/home';
        $this->load->view('partials/template', $view);
    }

    public function association()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

when I type: `http://localhost/mysite/association` I get `404`. Essentially I would like to use the same controller `Site` which is the default controller, to load multiple routers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using codeigniter and you can't access url lik below as you haven't defined any routes for that.
 `http://localhost/mysite/association` . You will have to go url like

```
http://localhost/mysite/site/association //sometimes need index.php
```

if you don't configure it. first parameter is the controller and second one is a method

For going to your custom URL you will have to go to application/config/routes.php and define your new custom

 route `$route['association'] = 'site/association';` 
You can also define like below routes and access from browser 
`$route['association/url1/url2/url2'] = 'site/association';` //simple

Hope that you have got your answer